# How to block ad.fly from linking to my domain?

Tags: spam

I see a lot of incoming links from ad.fly to my website. I assume that someone is using their service to link to my domain to make money through interstitial ads.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za4kc.jpg

I am looking for a way to block ad.fly from linking to my website. I assume that it is not possible as they are probably just creating a short link on their own end.

So, the workaround is that I want to block all incoming requests from ad.fly. Can this be done?

The website is running a vBulletin forum and is powered by a LAMP server.

Comment: You could also ask this on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @operamaniac What's your problem from extra traffic?!!

Comment: I do not want to give an impression that I am using ad.fly to spread the content on my own domain around social networks.